# Can't print PDF in Java

Tags: java, pdf, printing, pdfbox

I'm trying to print some PDFs using Java and I've found a few examples on how to do it. Seems pretty straight forward, but I've been running into problems the whole way.

I first tried PDFBox and it prints, but it doesn't print the document how it should look. A lot of the text gets garbled for some reason. So then I tried using the included Java packages [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10526325/1053066) and with an [example from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/appendix_printPS.fm.html) but nothing happens. I run the program, I check the print queue in the OS and the job is there, but the printer does nothing. My program exits gracefully with no errors and the print job goes away after a little while but there's still no action from the printer itself.

As an alternative, I've also tried running Adobe Acrobat from within my program but there are no command line arguments to enable duplexing which I need.

If anyone can either help me fix this, suggest another package or command line tool, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[I found this link helpful](http://java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/PDF/PDFBox-1.4.0/org/apache/pdfbox/PrintPDF.java.htm) ...Your mileage may vary...

The basic idea is to use the java.awt.print package and [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) (org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument)

PDFBox also has [command line options](http://pdfbox.apache.org/commandline/) to print, encrypt, decrypt, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I found for this matter: [ICEPDF](http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEpdf/overview.jsf).

Printing is 99% loyal to PDF seen on screen, allows silent printng and paper size changing. Only drawback, so far, is that I'm unable to show the print dialog, in same cases I need the user to be able to select printer, page size, number of copies, to name a few, this options are now selected prior by the user in an interface of my app.

Anyway, hope it helps!